# Where it Error?, i can't not see (BillNo)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

code in frm1,
this is create sub where orderId
in TbOrderMedicine col orderId

```
Sub New(ByVal orderId)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = " {TbOrderMedicine.orderId}='" & orderId & "' "
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

End Sub
```

code in btn printer BillN

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim Frm1 As New Form1(lbserviceid.Text)
        Frm1.Show()
    End Sub
```

**Photo Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove single quote from selection formula. It would be like:

```
CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = " {TbOrderMedicine.orderId}=" & orderId
```